# Getting notifications for functional location

Tags: sap-erp

Is it possible to get notifications for a functional location; as in: not link it to an equipment first, but just link it to the functional location? And if so, where is the connection between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications with functional location only (aka empty equipment) are created via `IW21` just fine.

[image]

If it's not the case for you then some customizing setting prevents it.

To find the link between the created notification and functional location use chain:

```
QMEL-qmnum = QMIH-qmnum >> 
             QMIH-iloan = ILOA-iloan >> 
                          ILOA-tplnr
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you tell me what the link is then? I know for example that the link between Equipment and Notification is the following: EQUI~EQUNR --> QMEL-->EQUNR. What if I wanted all notifications for a certain functional location? IFLOT~TPLNR --> ???

Comment: Updated the answer with linking stuff

Comment: That's the one I was looking for! Thanks!